# Do any commentaries suggest that the Tower of Babel was the Great Pyramid of Giza?

Tags: history, parashat-noach, genesis-bereishith, tower-of-babel

According to the Torah ([Genesis 11](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0111.htm)) the tower of Babel was located in [Shinar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinar), which scholars place in southern Mesopotamia, and was built at around ~ 1765 BC ([here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/timeline-for-the-history-of-judaism)).

The Great Pyramid of Giza was built between 2580 – 2560 BC and is not located in Babylonia or Mesopotamia. However, it stood as the largest man-made structure for ~3800 years. The Torah describes the attempt to build the Tower of Babel up to the heavens (Genesis 11:4 "וּמִגְדָּל וְרֹאשׁוֹ בַשָּׁמַיִם"). Although the Great Pyramid is understood to be a Pharaoh's tomb, the sheer height is unparalleled in comparison with all other ancient ziggurats/pyramids/structures in the general Middle-Eastern area.

Do any Jewish commentaries consider the Tower of Babel to be the Great Pyramid of Giza?

(related question: "[Is the Tower of Babel discussed in other Jewish texts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/is-the-tower-of-babel-discussed-in-other-jewish-texts)")

Comment: It seems doubtful, because the two were located in different places. The Tower was thought to be in Babylon while the Pyramid is in Egypt.

Comment: @Harel13 very true, I state this in the question. However, there are no shortages of disputes over locations in Tanach!

Comment: Sure, but not to the extent you're looking for. The sages and commentators knew where Babylon and Egypt were. It's also clear from Tanach that they were quite a way's apart from one another.

Comment: There's a midrash in Beresheet Rabbah that states that the person (or people) who first suggested to burn bricks to build the tower was/were Egypt. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.38.8?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: According to the Talmud in [Sanhedrin 109a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.109a.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) it seems the sages knew it was in Babylon itself and not Egypt, and possibly knew of the location of the remnants of the tower. And see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsippa).

Comment: The pyramids are made of stone, not brick.

Answer (score 1):

The apocryphal (or Midrash?) book of Jasher chapter 14 says that the first Pharaoh of Egypt was a wise man from Nimrod's nation of Shinar/Sumer. Shinar/Sumer being the location of the Tower of Babel, of course.

https://sacred-texts.com/chr/apo/jasher/14.htm

So the knowledge of how to build the Pyramid did come from Nimrod's Empire.

The apocryphal book of Jubilees says that the Tower of Babel was 5433 cubits tall (or 1.6 miles high), while the Great Pyramid is just 280 cubits high. The Tower of Babel is superior to the Great Pyramid of Giza. Giza is simply a remnant of Sumerian Nimrod knowledge, according to Jasher.